# possible matlab patch bug when accesing XData, YData, ZData, CData

Tags: matlab, patch

Suddenly I cannot access properly the data inside patches. This happens with different, separate computers, unmodified code that previously did not throw errors. I cannot find the explanation, I hope someone provides me the answer. The following instructions no longer works for me:

Option 1)

```
% get the patches in axes object
vector_patches = findobj(ax, 'Type','patch');

% we get for example the first patch
h_patch = vector_patches(1)

% display the x-y-z coordinates in column-wise: sometimes appears no data, other times it recovers succesfully the x and y, but not z..
disp([h_patch.XData', h_patch.YData', h_patch.ZData'])
```

Option 2)

```
% another way of accesing the data
vec_children = ax.Children; % get axes children

% we take the first object of vector. if it is patch...
if strcmp(get(vec_children(1),'Type','patch')),'patch')
    h_pat = vec_children(1);

    % then we extract in another way the data using get
    x_dat = get(h_pat,'XData');
    y_dat = get(h_pat,'YData');
    z_dat = get(h_pat,'ZData');

end %endif

% finally we try to display the results...
disp([x_dat', y_dat', z_dat'])
```

It always worked for me, but from today, with different computers, environments and matlab versions it works anylonger :( Could someone explains the reason? Thanks in advance

Comment: Which Matlab versions are you comparing?

Comment: R2016a with Win7-64, R2017a with Win10-64. It worked 1 year ago, 1 month ago, and yesterday. Today any longer.

Comment: It used to work but doesn't work anymore *on the same version of MATLAB*?

Comment: This is what fascinates me. I tried to reset the computers, etc. It is possible on-line update sync of any kind? (dll, etc). Please tell me if this still works on your computers guys

Comment: No, I don't think MATLAB does that. I have R2017a on MacOS and it works fine for me. -- What is "doesn't work"? Error message? Empty output array? -- Does your patch actually have data associated? It might be an empty patch?

Comment: Two symptoms. Case A): only XData and YData are succesfully extracted, but not ZData (returns empty [] for ZData). Case B): Empty matrix for all of them x,y,z. I have recovered right now an old script that worked and now works anylonger.. it is like I would have made something that changes external dll or whatever..

Comment: Did you check the validity of the patch object with `isvalid` before trying to pull data from it? What is the specific error message?

Comment: ZData is supposed to be empty if you have a 2D patch.

Comment: It throws no error, simply you don't recover what you expect. I will check the validity

Comment: Yeah yeah I know Cris, thank you. Anyway, I will report the mistery once I (hopefully) solve the issue

Comment: I don't think it is a bug at all. The code for displaying `patch` is correct and return the actual patch data. If your output is empty it means the patch has no data. We do not see how you are building your patches objects. It could very well be that you create several of them which are actually empty (so no display in the figure but you still retrieve their handle when you look for the figure children).

Comment: Please show the code that produces your patches, or try to reproduce this behaviour on a small example. You can read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Here back, I solved the problem. I found out that, at least in my context, if you create more than 100,000 patches in a single line using 'vertices' option, sometimes it creates empty [] values for XData, YData, ZData but not for CData. When you extract them they are empty, except one of them with all the geometrical info. Another problem I had comes from definition: you cannot define a patch in the way of patch(X,Y,Z) if there is no color input, but patch('XData',X, 'YData',Y, 'ZData',Z), or C is another structure, e.g. using 'FaceColor','interp'. I will read howto minimal examples Hoki, thx